# How to convert UTM to long/Lat while the points distributed over different zones 38,39,40,41

Tags: r, leaflet

I am going to convert over ten thousand UTM data points to long/lat coordination system. My points distributed over four zones 38,39,40 and 41 in Iran. To be reproducible my code, I made a 100 random samples set of my points in following code. As presented in following code when I select zone 39 all of points will be shown in zone 39 on leflet map. when you change the zone to 38 all points will shift to zone 38 and so on. My question is how can I handle this code in a way to coordinate each point to its real correct geographical point. is there any way to find zone number from UTM to make the code conditional for different zones. Thanks

```
 utmx<-c(453199, 452226, 459070, 456923 ,406917, 439882, 406917, 453199, 452226, 459070, 456923 ,439882, 452226 , 459070, 456923 ,406917, 439882 ,453199 ,452226 ,459070 ,456923 ,406917, 360103, 360103, 439000, 453400,414114, 413937, 410250, 402673 ,348019 ,346225 ,351019, 339701, 335818, 361243, 360250, 379132, 375932 , 379140, 362556, 360103, 423200, 439000, 414114, 413937, 410250, 402673, 393698, 361243, 356800, 365150 , 360250, 379132, 375932, 379140, 393917, 401315, 362556, 360103, 348019, 346225, 351019, 335818, 338793, 393698, 361243, 356800, 365150, 360250, 362556, 360103, 439000, 414114, 413937, 410250, 402673, 348019 , 351019, 339701, 335818, 333066, 338793, 326138, 361243, 356800, 365150, 360250, 379132, 379140, 393917 , 401315, 360103, 414114, 413937, 410250, 402673, 393698, 356800, 365150)


 utmy<-c(4094292, 4095754, 4091838, 4092360, 4084991, 4095385 ,4084991, 4094292, 4095754, 4091838, 4092360, 4095385, 4095754, 4091838, 4092360 ,4084991, 4095385 ,4094292, 4095754 ,4091838 ,4092360, 4084991,4067970 ,4067970 ,4020600 ,4020400, 4081856 ,4083323 ,4082400, 4087420, 4102943 ,4115011, 4111792, 4139663, 4133857, 4071241, 4078450, 4059477, 4059055, 4059506 ,4069070 ,4067970, 4113100, 4020600, 4081856, 4083323, 4082400 ,4087420, 4068252, 4071241, 4082850, 4078100, 4078450,4059477 ,4059055, 4059506, 4063361, 4069043, 4069070, 4067970, 4102943, 4115011 ,4111792, 4133857 ,4120862, 4068252,4071241, 4082850 ,4078100 ,4078450, 4069070 ,4067970 ,4020600 ,4081856 ,4083323 ,4082400, 4087420,4102943, 4111792, 4139663, 4133857, 4138934 ,4120862 ,4131102 ,4071241, 4082850, 4078100, 4078450, 4059477, 4059506, 4063361, 4069043, 4067970, 4081856, 4083323 ,4082400 ,4087420 ,4068252,4082850,
         4078100)

body<-data.frame(utmx,utmy)

###For Iran
wgs84 = "+init=epsg:4326"  #this need to be checked
bng = "+proj=utm +zone=39 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
### 

##########Conversion function
library(rgdal)
ConvertCoordinates <- function(easting,northing) {
  out = cbind(easting,northing)
  mask = !is.na(easting)
  sp <-  sp::spTransform(sp::SpatialPoints(list(easting[mask],northing[mask]),proj4string=sp::CRS(bng)),sp::CRS(wgs84))
  out[mask,]=sp@coords
  out
}
########### Conversion using above function and checking with web convertor
LongLat<-ConvertCoordinates(body$utmx,body$utmy)
colnames(LongLat)<-c("lon","lat")
body<-cbind(body, LongLat ) 

###############################first prepare a leaflet plot ...

lplot <- leaflet::leaflet(data = body) %>% # create leaflet object
  leaflet::addTiles() %>% # add basemap
  #leaflet::addCircleMarkers( clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())# add data layer - markers
  leaflet::addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

lplot #  ... then display it
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you have is the coordinate numbers and not the zone identifier then there's no way of knowing which of *any* of the UTM zones your points are in. The UTM coordinate numbers are repeated for each zone, and only the zone identifier can tell you which zone a point is in. The point (453199,4094292) could be anywhere in the world, never mind just those four zones in Iran.

You need to go back to your source and get the UTM zone information for each point, and then you can construct the correct projection string for each point, and do the transformation for each different UTM zone you have to get the lat-long coordinates.